# Restful web service not working after java downgrade

Tags: jboss

My sample restful web service was working fine with Java 1.8 but it is not working with 1.7.

I am getting the error message

`org/jboss/resteasy/spi/ResteasyDeployment : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

Comment: Please provide code or error messages and describe your problem with more details.

Comment: HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(9000), 14);
  HttpContextBuilder contextBuilder = new HttpContextBuilder();
  contextBuilder.getDeployment().getActualResourceClasses().add(ResourceConfig.class);